# Exporting Python's script errors/traceback to file with netcat

Tags: files, python, netcat, stderr

I have a Python script accessible with netcat: `nc 'serverIP' port`.

The Python script awaits an input from the user. If the input is expected, the script keeps running. If the input is unexpect (e.g. string instead of integer), it exits and disconnect netcat.

```
# Outline of Python2 script

def play()
    user_choice = int(input('your choice'))
    computer_choice # depending on user_choice

    # if user wins then open and read file.txt
```

I'd like to catch the error message from Python traceback to a local file before being disconnected.

From other questions/forums, I've tried to redirect stderr to a file:

```
nc -zv IP port 2> | grep open | tee report.txt

nc -vv -z IP port > file.txt 2>
```

I received zsh parse errors from the above commands.

I also tried to send my input to netcat and save to a file both stdout and stderr:

```
echo 'my input' | nc 'serverIP' port > report.txt
```

but it looks like the input is sent before the Python script is ready to catch the input (my understanding...).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: not sure I catch what you want, python traceback (the dump of the stack) will be seen on server ( `serverIP` in your sample) host, not local host.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is there anyway to catch this traceback and pipe it to a file in netcat?

Comment: Redirect stderr to stdout in your python script.   There are some examples of stderr redirection in python on Stack Overflow: [How to redirect stderr in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956142/how-to-redirect-stderr-in-python).

Comment: You should show your (simplified) Python code as a [mre] and explain what input/output you use/expect and what error/traceback you want to get. Note that you may have difficulties distinguishing between normal output and error messages as `nc` uses a single TCP connection only.

Comment: I've edited with an outline of the Python script. This is part of a cybersecurity challenge. I've managed to exploit the vulnerability of Python2 input() with a command line to read the file. But I'm tricked with the int() function that expects a number string. Using the script locally I get a traceback ValueError giving me the content of the file. That is this ValueError that I'd like to catch from the server with netcat...